# reactjs node_modules not found

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, terminal

So i ran `npx create-react-app my-app` on a specific folder in my documents directory and everything is installed including node_modules but when i try to run `npm start` it says that react-scripts.js under Documents directory which is outside the folder that i created in Documents directory.
I don't if this has anything to do with the case that I installed VSCODE on my SSD drive and I moved my documents directory over the other HDD drive so it might've messed everything up.

Basically I'm working on F:/ drive which is the HDD drive :
`F:\21655\Documents\Design & Build\chat\my-app>` I run this `npm start` and the terminal says `Error: Cannot find module 'F:\21655\Documents\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'`
As I said the node_modules exists already in my-app directory.

Comment: after creating an app with `create-react-app`, you should `cd` to its directory and then run `npm start`. the error you get means it probably found a node modules on your parent directory. (when npm can't find a nodemodules directly in the current folder, it looks in the parent folders.)

Comment: Please read the post I already said that I ran npm start under the project directory (my-app) which does contain all the node_modules

Comment: maybe it's because there is a space in your path (`Design & Build`). try creating a project on the root like `f:` and check if it works.